# The / location 301-redirects to itself in a loop

Tags: redirect

Lets say my Wordpress site is https://example.com, and when I visit it, I keep getting 301 redirected to https://example.com. This happens only with `/`, all other pages are working.

I have tried to eliminate the usual suspects:

- **Plugins**: disabled all, didn't help
- **Theme**: switched to the default one, didn't help
- **HTTPs**: no, because `/contact-us`, `/wp-admin/` and everything else works with HTTPs and the certificate is valid
- **www**: no, the domain does not have a www prefix, the redirect has the 'naked' domain
- **.htaccess**: renamed to something else to disable it, didn't help
- **The static page itself**: works when assigned a slug and visited directly, e.g. `/home`; assigning an otherwise working page to be the Front Page doesn't help either
- *Settings* → *Reading* → **Your homepage displays**:

  - **A static page** having a selected front page:

    - navigating to `/` 301 redirects back to `/` in a loop ← this is the whole problem
    - navigating to `/index.php` actually displays the selected front page
  - When selecting **Your latest posts**:

    - navigating to `/` works, lists the latest posts
    - navigating to `/index.php` redirects to `/`

Lastly, this website is a duplicate copy of another website that works fine. I have changed `wp-config.php` to connect to a different database, as well as the `wp_options` table to have `example.com` as a `siteurl` and `home`.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy that forwards via port 80 / non https? Are you sure the redirect is coming from WP and not web server?

Comment: Hi @kero, This happens on a Hostinger shared account, so I doubt they're doing something extraordinary with their configuration. As for myself, no, I'm not behind a proxy, and we've tried it on different computers on completely different networks